# install mysql and mysql2 gems fail on fedora16

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

**this is my command info:**

```
[root@Lil lib]# gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
creating Makefile
```

**and when i input the command"gem install mysql2"， the info was：**

```
[root@Lil lib]# gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile
**this is my gem list:**
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
actionmailer (3.2.11)
actionpack (3.2.11)
activemodel (3.2.11)
activerecord (3.2.11)
activeresource (3.2.11)
activesupport (3.2.11)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.3)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.6)
libv8 (3.11.8.13 x86_64-linux)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mongrel_cluster (1.0.5)
multi_json (1.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.4)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.11)
railties (3.2.11)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12)
ref (1.0.2)
sprockets (2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
therubyracer (0.11.3)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
```

**I'v tried a lot of methods but still can't solve the problem ,what should i do?**

Comment: I suggest using the [package](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ruby-mysql) for your platform.

Comment: I tried just now,but it did not work~~thinks!

Comment: I means that I installed the mysql package successfully but still can not install mysql2 gem.

Comment: Copy and paste the exact error you're getting, also there is a ruby-mysql package for Fedora16, see the link in my previous comment

Comment: I installed the rpm with the link you gived,and then I tired to install the mysql2 gem,the error info was: [root@Lil zhanlgei]# gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

Comment: Do you have the mysql development package installed? Put the entire build log (including everything up to the next shell prompt) in a pastebin and let me know where it is.

Comment: I have installed 'mysql-devel' by yum.the total info when install mysql2 is：[root@Lil zhanlgei]# gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

Comment: .....
gcc -shared -o mysql2.so mysql2_ext.o client.o result.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -Wl,-z,relro  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/mysql    -lruby -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../libz.so when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld 返回 1
make: *** [mysql2.so] 错误 1

Comment: Upgrade zlib to the latest version?

Comment: yeah!~the gem installed success! think you hd1!

Comment: Then I'll condense it to an answer for you to accept, ok?

Comment: yeah~~!You gave me a great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

[root@Lil zhanlgei]# gem install mysql2 Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR: Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no checking for mysql.h... yes checking for errmsg.h... yes checking for mysqld_error.h... yes creating Makefile

Do you have the mysql development package installed? Put the entire build log (including everything up to the next shell prompt)

I have installed 'mysql-devel' by yum.the total info when install mysql2 is：[root@Lil zhanlgei]# gem install mysql2 Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR: Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no checking for mysql.h... yes checking for errmsg.h... yes checking for mysqld_error.h... yes creating Makefile
..... gcc -shared -o mysql2.so mysql2_ext.o client.o result.o -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/mysql -lruby -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm -lc /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../libz.so when searching for -lz /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

Upgrade zlib to the latest version.

yeah!~the gem installed success! think you hd1!